# Jhister and UML modeling

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to use Jhipster with UML Designer.
I have created a uml diagram.
When I run jhipster-uml model.uml I am getting a

> ? Please choose between the available Editors: umldesigner
>   Creating:
>     Hike
>   Object # has no method 'spawnSync' TypeError: Object
>    has no method 'spawnSync'
>       at /usr/lib/node_modules/jhipster-uml/jhipster-uml.js:140:19
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at createEntities (/usr/lib/node_modules/jhipster-uml/jhipster-uml.js:130:20)
>       at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/jhipster-uml/jhipster-uml.js:101:3)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>       at startup (node.js:119:16)

Does anyone know about it?

Thanks

Comment: I am also getting same error.

Comment: I was using nodejs to run jhipster-uml, then i was getting this error. But when i change the command to node it worked.